# Synchronizing MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, database

I have a maintanance problem synchronizing my MySQL data bases . These are the databases I have :

1. My development DB : Here I make my curret development changes .
2. Staging DB : I need to make all the changes I did in the development on it before using , currently I hold migration scripts for structure and data.
3. Production DB : A production environment . Have to do exacly the same as the staging .

My problem , is sync. the structure , and some of the data. This is really a very hard work to maintaine.
Is there any technics , tools to do with MySQL . What is replication , is it good for my situation , how to use it .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Have you considered simply making dumps and importing them into the other databases?

Comment: I need to add only new things and don't delete or ovveride what exists . Also dumps still seems to me a manual way and need efforts to sync it with the current DB .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product that I have used for many years is [Navicat MySQL edition](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql).  The program works well for both structure and data synchronization.  You can do one-way or two-way synchronizations. The version I have is 7.2.10 and its main limitation is that it doesn't handle VIEWS, TRIGGERS, or STORED PROCEDURES.  I am sure the newer versions do handle this.